# Same content on several different computers/monitors administered remotely

Tags: windows, sharing

I currently have several PC+TV combos set up around the building, I would like a way to be able to show the same powerpoint/IE-tab/spreadsheet/video on all of those computers at the same time, and be able to change what is shown from one of them, instead of going around changing content on all of them.

They are running windows 7, and they are all logged in with the same windows user, and are on the same LAN and WAN.

Anyone got any software recommendations for this particular problem? If not, anyone know where I should go to ask for help?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You **could** use VNC (whcih was my first thought), but that means remoting in to each device, which is a problem if you have many. Also, they won't all be updated simultaneously.

You want a solution where you make a single change and they are all updated automagically.

Can you display all of your potential data in the browser? If so, just run a browser on each device which points to a given URL - and then switch the content of that URL when you want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a VNC server on the machine from which you're controlling what's displayed and a VNC client on each of the others which simply displays whatever the server displays:

- you can also share app control with other clients
- you can also throw other OSes in the mix: mac, linux, etc
- you can mix users as well if you need (doesn't have to be the same
  user)

Doesn't support sharing the sound, tho, if you need sound as well you need to complement it with an audio/phone conferencing solution.

Several free VNC packages available out there.